# Show that a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined as

$$
 f(x,y) = \cases{\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, (x,y)\neq (0,0)
                 \\ 0, (x,y)=(0,0)   }.
$$

Then how can I show that this function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$? [This lecture note](http://math.caltech.edu/~ma108a/notesderivatice.pdf) says that this is because the "possible derivative is not a linear function." But I just don't understand what it really means by that. I'll appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, $Df((0,0))$, if it exists, is a "bounded linear map $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$".

(If you have some background in linear algebra then you know that such a map can be represented by a $1 \times 2$-matrix, i.e. $Df((0,0)) = (a \, b)$ for some $a,b \in \Bbb R$.)

Now if $Df((0,0))$ were to exist, then combining Lemma 1.2 of your notes with the calculation of the example establishes that the effect of this *linear* map on $(h_1,h_2)$ is in fact... not linear, but equal to $f(h_1,h_2)$ (in particular, it's not an additive map). Thus $Df((0,0))$ cannot exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. :D

Comment: Glad to help you out. Understanding the examples is always the first step to a good understanding of the subject as a whole :).

Comment: What was lemma $1.2$?  The link is dead